# How do I evenly space out only the (-) (0) and (+) portions, with the title having its own space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to adjust:

[image: What I'm trying to adjust]

Here is my current CSS and HTML code (entirely) that houses these radio buttons. Attached as JS Fiddle so you can view as snippet. Line 8676 is where CSS code for inner shape is, and line 4565 for outer shape.:

```css
.me-2 {
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.btn-toolbar {
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups" style="text-align: right; margin-bottom: 7px;">
  <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/search?path=soldandshippedby0enrchstring%253ABest%2BBuy&search=officejet+pro';">Demos - OJ Pro</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">-</button>
    <button-disabled type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">0</button-disabled>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how if I adjust the size of the outer shape, pressing the inner button (i.e + button) has a different shape than the outer. I'm having trouble essentially linking it together such that I have:

1. The (-), (0), and (+) buttons are aligned right of this pill shape and have even spacing inside such that they are square buttons of the same size.
2. The title (i.e Demos - OJ Pro) is aligned left, without ruining the spacing and alignment of the -,0,+ ... Can make this a fixed size/space upto the buttons on the right.

*Also, do not care for desktop format. This web app will only be used on mobile*

I realize that the "title" of the block is the same CSS styling as the -,+,0 ... but is there a way I can achieve what I noted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at CSS Grids?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.container.sm {
  width: 50%;
}

.container.xs {
  width: 33%;
}

.container.xxs {
  width: 25%;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
}

.btn-wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-label {
  padding-left: 16px;
  justify-content: start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-action {
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-action:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 12.5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12.5px;
}

.btn-action:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  outline: none;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-label">Label</div>
    <div class="btn-action">+</div>
    <div class="btn-action">0</div>
    <div class="btn-action">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-label">Label</div>
    <div class="btn-action">+</div>
    <div class="btn-action">0</div>
    <div class="btn-action">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container sm">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-label">Label</div>
    <div class="btn-action">+</div>
    <div class="btn-action">0</div>
    <div class="btn-action">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container xs">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-label">Label</div>
    <div class="btn-action">+</div>
    <div class="btn-action">0</div>
    <div class="btn-action">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container xxs">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-label">Label</div>
    <div class="btn-action">+</div>
    <div class="btn-action">0</div>
    <div class="btn-action">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I just learnt this. Is there a way to implement this into my current code? I currently have an outer shape CSS and inner shape CSS as shown on JSFiddle link.

Comment: @UsamaSaleem probably yes - Bootstrap 5.1 has it already ([experimentally](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/)). Unfortunately, your CSS is huge, so it might take some serious effort for someone not familiar with the logic to help implementing this

Comment: Or, you could just add some custom CSS (not bootstrap) & go with that. CSS Grids is awesome (just a hint: search for it e.g. on Youtube)

Comment: Thank you so much. I added some grid elements to it and im already almost there. It fixed all the spacing, just need to play around with the amount of spacing now to fully make it pretty. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @UsamaSaleem glad I could help! Experiment with this feature - very strong, very flexible and can be used to solve layout issues that gave a headache previously :)